# How to retrieve versioned images in Genetics Mesh?

Tags: gentics-mesh

I am going through the demo project, and updated an Image node `VEHICLE IMAGES` in the UI (PROJECTS / DEMO / VEHICLE IMAGES)

I have updated the `VEHICLEIMAGE` schema, with property `autoPurge: false`.

Now I am able to see the previous versions and each version of the node. But the binary image file still remains the same for all the versions.

I tried this API, http://localhost:8080/api/v2/demo/nodes/e4298e03bd9547a9a98e03bd95f7a990/binary/image?versions=0.1

`vehicle image node: e4298e03bd9547a9a98e03bd95f7a990`

Please let know the possibility of getting the versioned image content

Answer (score 0):

The correct parameter name is **version=0.1**, not version**s**. Everything else looks correct.

https://getmesh.io/docs/api/#project__nodes__nodeUuid__binary__fieldName__get

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't looked this small mistake.